# Syntax for STUFF/FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong syntactically to be getting

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

I boiled down my query for readability and am still getting the error in the various ways I've tried to execute it:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT * 
           FROM
               (SELECT N',' + N'first' 
                UNION 
                SELECT N',' + N'second') 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT * 
           FROM
               (SELECT N',' + N'first' 
                UNION 
                SELECT N',' + N'second')) 
           FOR XML PATH(''), 1, 1, '')
```

For a while I was getting

> The FOR XML clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the `SELECT` containing a set operator using derived table syntax and apply FOR XML on top of it.

but amended the code per [ExactHelp's post](http://www.exacthelp.com/2012/04/for-xml-clause-is-invalid-in-views.html).

**UPDATE**

Based on answer from @NenadZivkovic I came up with the following which did what I was looking to do:

```
WITH CTE_perca_categories AS
(
    SELECT 
        category = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + category 
                          FROM perca_categories 
                          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
) , CTE_perca_tags AS
(
    SELECT tag = (SELECT ', ' + tag from perca_tags FOR XML PATH(''))
)
SELECT 
    CONCAT((SELECT * FROM CTE_perca_categories),
           (SELECT * FROM CTE_perca_tags))
```

Output (where tag begins with 'Food'):

```
Charitable Giving, Nondiscretionary Spending, Saving, Discretionary Spending, Food, Dining, Groceries, Bills
```

Comment: You're writing this from scratch? memory? There are hundreds of blog posts and answers with working examples of this syntax. Why don't yuo take one of those and adapt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with neither `STUFF` nor `FOR XML`. It's simply syntax error with selecting from subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N',' + N'first' UNION SELECT N',' + N'second')
```

You need to give alias to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N',' + N'first' UNION SELECT N',' + N'second') AS x
```

After which you'll get error that you need to name a column 1 of 'x', so you should add that alias as well.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT N',' + N'first' as Col1 UNION SELECT N',' + N'second') x
```

Your whole query will now look like this:

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT N',' + N'first' AS Col1 UNION SELECT N',' + N'second') AS x FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

It will work, but I am pretty sure the result it gives is not exactly what you are looking for.

```
(No column name)
--------------------------------------
Col1>,first</Col1><Col1>,second</Col1>
```

You are probably looking to concatenate the string from your sub-query?
That should look something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Source AS 
(
    SELECT N',' + N'first' AS Col1 UNION SELECT N',' + N'second'
)
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF
(
    (SELECT '' + Col1 FROM CTE_Source FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
) 
FROM CTE_Source
```

to get:

```
(No column name)
---------------
first,second
```

Comment: your answer helped me so much, thank you. See my update for what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the microsoft doc that talks about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql

So, the question is:

> Is the following a valid character_expression?

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT N',' + N'first' UNION SELECT N',' + N'second') FOR XML PATH(''))
```

The character_expression has to evaluate to obtain a single data value.

From [For XML - SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server)

> The FOR XML clause can be used in top-level queries and in sub queries. The top-level FOR XML clause can be used only in the SELECT statement. In sub queries, FOR XML can be used in the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. It can also be used in assignment statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change your query to

```
select stuff(
  (select ','+a from 
      (SELECT 'first' a UNION ALL
       SELECT 'second' ) ttt 
   FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'') b;
```

As Nenad pointed out it is important that the subquery's column *has* a name and that the concatenated column for the `for XML path` clause does *not* have a column name.